# Algorithm for finding Time Complexity of Algorithm

Tags: complexity-theory, computation-theory

I understand that it is possible to analyse code and manually calculate the time complexity of an algorithm by hand and then determine the *Big O* notation. However I am curious if an algorithm exists to **automatically** compute this problem.

Comment: Very likely there is no such algorithm as I assume you can reduce this to the halting problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem